# How can I make an auto clicker with pyautogui only when I activate it

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have been wanting to make this for a while and have finally gotten around to it. But could not get it to work. I need it to be able to work on macOS Linux and windows, I also need it to be able to be deactivated and activated with the press of a button.
This is what I have tried.
`
import pyautogui
import time

while True:
cookie = pyautogui.locate("cookie.png")
pyautogui.click("cookie.png")
`

Comment: Can you include part of the code you've tried? Maybe you saw some exception or something was not right, we can help with that

Comment: Can you include it by editing the question please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check if "cookie.png" looks the same in macOS, Linux and Windows. If it does not then you may need two or three different **.png**

Second, the code is quite ok. If you want to stop the clicking then you can use the library [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) (better than pyautogui for keyboard control). Then you can define the keyword to stop the clicking.